# Linksys wireless model WPC 300N V1 network adapter

Tags: drivers

I plan to install ubuntu on an old Dell Latitude C640 (mfr. 2003) and will increase RAM to 1GB.  It has a Linksys Wireless N network adapter (model WPC300N V1).  Two questions, what version of ubuntu should I download/install and will the Linksys wireless adapter work?

Answer (score 0):

**1) will the network adapater work?** 
googling I found a solution right away where they used an ndiswrapper, so it should. 
**2) What version to use?**
The specs arn't great but in theory, you should be able to run regular Ubuntu on it. In the real world though, your ram will be just sufficient but i fear your processor will prove too limited. Therefore i would try Lubuntu.
gd luck!